# std::cin function not acting as expected?

Tags: c++

I created a function which takes a string for a message and an input value (primarily an integer, at least in this case) so I can print a message and take an input in a single function instead of two lines of code. Here is the snippet:

main.h

```
void input(std::string msg, int choice) {
    std::cout << msg;
    std::cin >> choice;
}
```

However, when passing the function in my main function, it doesn't perform the same way this would:

main.cpp (working code with expected result)

```
int initial_choice;
std::cout << "Invalid input provided. Please try again: ";
std::cin >> initial_choice;
```

main.cpp (working code with unexpected result)

```
int initial_choice;
input("Invalid input provided. Please try again: ", initial_choice);
```

When it comes to the snippet with the expected result, my switch case function properly detects the input (in this case it is initial_choice) as a valid integer. For example, entering 1, 2, or 3 will work with case 1:, case 2:, and case 3:. However, the snippet with the unexpected result doesn't detect any of the three valid numbers in my switch case function, instead they all run the code under the default case.

Comment: You should read about pass-by-value and pass-by-reference in C++.

Comment: When you pass a variable as `int choice`, the compiler actually makes a copy of the parameter. Therefore, modifications to `choice` happen on the copy, not the original. Passing by reference ensures that all references to `choice` affect the original.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with `cin`, `cout`, switch statements, etc.

As user202729 has pointed out, it is a simple matter of function parameter-passing.

C++ is not Fortran III; by default, parameters to functions are passed by value, not by reference. This means that if within a function you change the value of one of its parameters, this change will only be in effect within the function; the change will not be reflected to the caller.

So, your `std::cin >> choice;` statement works perfectly well, and it stores the value entered by the user in your `choice` variable.  However, this value forever ceases to exist once the function ends, and it is never reflected back to the caller, which in this case is the `initial_choice` variable of your `main()` method.

To fix this, you have two options:

1. Pass the variable by reference, so that the function can modify it.
2. Do not pass the variable at all; instead, have the function return the value; that's generally what functions are for.